# A query on HTML and CSS - There is white gap above header section. How to deal with this?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic query regarding the HTML and CSS. Please see the below code

```css
body {
font: 12px/1.5 arial;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0
}


header {
background-color: #35424a;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 0;
}

.container{
width: 80%;
margin:auto;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
       <div class = "container">
         <div id="branding">
            <h1>TEST HTML</h1>
         </div>
             <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">HOME<a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT<a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES<a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
       </div>
      </header>
  </body>
```

My problem with this code is that you can see there is gap between the header section and browser. How to fill this gap?

Please see the below screenshot

[image]

I tried using the `margin-top:0` even I was unable to fill this. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can inspect your html with `F12` on most browsers? Then hovering around would have lead you to that `h1` margins

Comment: 6 answers, all saying the same thing... necessary?

Comment: Thank you all. I cannot mark as answer in first 10 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the margin top on the `h1`.

```
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
font: 12px/1.5 arial;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0
}
h1 {
margin-top: 0;
  }


header {
background-color: #35424a;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 0;
}

.container{
width: 80%;
margin:auto;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
       <div class = "container">
         <div id="branding">
            <h1>TEST HTML</h1>
         </div>
             <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">HOME<a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT<a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES<a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
       </div>
      </header>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example. You need to set h1 margin to 0. I would suggest to you that you start using some [css reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/), that would reset all the browsers default styles.

```css
body {
font: 12px/1.5 arial;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0
}


header {
background-color: #35424a;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 0;
}

.container{
width: 80%;
margin:auto;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
       <div class = "container">
         <div id="branding">
            <h1>TEST HTML</h1>
         </div>
             <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">HOME<a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT<a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES<a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
       </div>
      </header>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `h1` tag take the `16px` top and bottom margin so need to add `header h1{margin:0}`

```css
body {
font: 12px/1.5 arial;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0
}


header {
background-color: #35424a;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 0;
}

.container{
width: 80%;
margin:auto;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff
}
header h1{margin:0}
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
       <div class = "container">
         <div id="branding">
            <h1>TEST HTML</h1>
         </div>
             <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">HOME<a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT<a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES<a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
       </div>
      </header>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to reset all margin padding for all element using * selector.

```
*{ padding:0; margin:0 }
h1 { padding-top:10px }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the margin from `h1`, the styling inherited from the browser default (user agent stylesheet).

[image]

To minimize that

```
h1{margin:0};
```

Although I suggest you should add an id or css class to it for better maintainability

Answer (score 0):

> body tag has a default 4px padding just remove that 
>   just add these lines in your html/css projects so that everyting by defualt setting overruled by this

```
*{ 
  padding : 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box ;
}
```